# PyV8 failing to install with pip, does not compile in Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, python, pip

I am having the exact same issue as here: https://code.google.com/p/pyv8/issues/detail?id=132, but answer didn't work either.

I am trying to install PyV8 using pip in Fedora 20. I get this:

```
$ pip install pyv8

x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread -fPIC -DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB -Ilib/python/inc -Ilib/boost/inc -Ilib/v8/inc -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/Engine.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/Engine.o

In file included from src/Context.h:7:0,

             from src/Engine.h:7,

             from src/Engine.cpp:1:

src/Wrapper.h: In member function ‘const boost::python::api::object& CJavascriptArray::ArrayIterator::dereference() const’:

src/Wrapper.h:115:66: warning: returning reference to temporary [enabled by default]

x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread -fPIC -DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB -Ilib/python/inc -Ilib/boost/inc -Ilib/v8/inc -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/Wrapper.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/Wrapper.o

In file included from src/Wrapper.cpp:1:0:

src/Wrapper.h: In member function ‘const boost::python::api::object& CJavascriptArray::ArrayIterator::dereference() const’:

src/Wrapper.h:115:66: warning: returning reference to temporary [enabled by default]

src/Wrapper.cpp: In static member function ‘static void CPythonObject::SetupObjectTemplate(v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate>)’:

src/Wrapper.cpp:311:84: error: invalid conversion from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Boolean> (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, const v8::AccessorInfo&)’ to ‘v8::NamedPropertyQuery {aka v8::Handle<v8::Integer> (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, const v8::AccessorInfo&)}’ [-fpermissive]

/usr/include/v8.h:2392:8: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetNamedPropertyHandler(v8::NamedPropertyGetter, v8::NamedPropertySetter, v8::NamedPropertyQuery, v8::NamedPropertyDeleter, v8::NamedPropertyEnumerator, v8::Handle<v8::Value>)’ [-fpermissive]

src/Wrapper.cpp:312:94: error: invalid conversion from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Boolean> (*)(uint32_t, const v8::AccessorInfo&) {aka v8::Handle<v8::Boolean> (*)(unsigned int, const v8::AccessorInfo&)}’ to ‘v8::IndexedPropertyQuery {aka v8::Handle<v8::Integer> (*)(unsigned int, const v8::AccessorInfo&)}’ [-fpermissive]

/usr/include/v8.h:2415:8: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetIndexedPropertyHandler(v8::IndexedPropertyGetter, v8::IndexedPropertySetter, v8::IndexedPropertyQuery, v8::IndexedPropertyDeleter, v8::IndexedPropertyEnumerator, v8::Handle<v8::Value>)’ [-fpermissive]

error: command 'x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++' failed with exit status 1
```

It says there is an invalid conversion error.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You should explain what your issue is, that link is down, and what you've already tried so we don't repeat the same things

Comment: The link is not down from here. I edited and explained more. I don't know what to try.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev
sudo easy_install greenlet
sudo easy_install gevent
git clone https://github.com/buffer/pyv8.git
cd pyv8
sudo python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Consider adding a few sentences for context to help readers understand why this solves the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you add an explanation?